# Why does this "if" statement placement work

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why the first code works and the 2nd doesnt. I thought the second code would work. It is supposed to return click number until 5 and then print "enough already". But I don't know why the second code doesnt work. the only difference is that I change the placement of the "if"

```
function buttonClicked() {
    let counter = 0;
    $(".clicker").click(function(event) {
        counter += 1;
        $(".clicks").html(`${counter} Clicks`)
        if (counter > 5) {
            $(".clicks").html("enough already")
        }
    })
}


function buttonClicked() {
    var counter = 0;
    $(".clicker").click(function(event) {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter > 5) {
            $(".clicks").html("enough already")
            $(".clicks").html(`${counter} Clicks`)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You never set the text of `clicks` unless `counter > 5` in the second code

Comment: You're setting the click count only when the counter is larger than 5.

Answer (score 1):

The second code doesn't work because you only display the click counter when click counter is larger than 5.

Here's your second code with clearer format.

```
if (counter > 5){
    $(".clicks").html("enough already")
    $(".clicks").html(`${counter} Clicks`) //this should be outside 
}
```

Working code (the first one):

```
$(".clicks").html(`${counter} Clicks`) //update value per click (correct)
if (counter > 5){
    $(".clicks").html("enough already")
}
```